# c++ - looking up sparse matrix values without loops

Tags: c++, hashtable, sparse-matrix

I have a C++ program that is expecting an input file in the format:

```
X    Y    Z
1    1    .642
1.1  1    .482
1.2  1    .394
1.3  1    .420
1.4  1    .948
```

The text file is very long - roughly 20,000 lines or so.  I now need to read this in to my C++ program in order to do Z lookup for any (X,Y) pair.  If the (X,Y) pair is not exactly the same as any in my input file, I need to use the closest X and closest Y value.  If I had a full matrix instead of just the nonzero values, the X and Y coordinates would be evenly spaced.

My problem is in determining the fastest way to do this.  I want to avoid actually searching through a vector for the closest X, then searching through a vector for the closest Y.  Is there a way to accomplish this without looping and searching?  Would some sort of hashtable work for looking up the values?

I'm a scripting guy and a c++ newbie so I apologize if this seems trivial.  So for reference I need the fast way to do:

```
lookup(1.1,1)
    >>> .482

lookup(1.112, 1)
    >>> .482 // value corresponding to closest x and closest y

lookup(0,0)
    >>> .642 // value corresponding to closest x and closest y
```

This is possible directly if I had the full matrix, for example:

```
    1.1  1.2  1.3  1.4  1.5
1.1
1.3
1.5      (Z values)
1.7
1.9
```

In order to find the Z value pertaining to (1.5, 1.2) I can simply return the Z value found at index [1.5/(x_spacing), 1.2/(y_spacing)].

Granted I also need to subtract my lookup values by this spacing, and round if the exact (X,Y) pair is not present.  The bottom line is, however, that it allows me to get the appropriate Z value without doing any searching.  I want to accomplish the same thing, except without taking up all the space that the giant full matrix would require.  That is why the text file only contains pairs corresponding to nonzero Z values.

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you mean to ask if there is a way to parse the file in a sparse manner? Maybe only read in parts of it depending on the lookup?

Comment: I want to read in the entire text file and store it in such a way that when I go to look up a value, I can do it without "searching" for the correct X and Y keys.

Comment: So just use a Quad tree as suggested in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest storing it in a structured tree. A quad tree for example. It will be sparse storage for space saving and it is also very easy to search for closest point.

A tutorial on Quad Trees in c++ is [here](http://veeableful.wordpress.com/2012/02/07/algorithm-space-partitioning-using-quadtree/).

Comment: I considered using a tree.  I guess what I am really asking is if there is a way (similar to a hash table) to take any X,Y pair and get Z directly.  This would be possible with a full table.  For example I could take any x value, divide by the difference between X coordinates (assuming equally spaced) and that gives me the proper index.  I want to accomplish the same thing without having to actually store the entire full matrix.

Comment: Well a hashtable would work except that it would be very difficult to search for a close position if the x y you want doesn't exist.

Comment: Is there any other method that might give me ~ O(1) complexity?  Is there other information I could possibly provide in the file from the first program (generating the file) so this might be possible?

Comment: only an array type (as in store the data based on its x y component in a huge map) will give you O(1) access, but it will be much worse for searching. It is also not sparse in any way.